# Is there a good web based deploy tool for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment

How can i manage deployment in multiple machines in different environments?. i.e Online based deployment tool for rails.

Comment: I can't tell, are you looking for something like [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/)?

Comment: With [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/) it is easy to deploy your source to different server.

Answer (score 2):

You can use capistrano and an online code repository such as github to deploy from a remote repository using git or svn. I'd say this is what pretty much every rails developer does.

http://help.github.com/deploy-with-capistrano/